# How to iterate over JSON objects in bash without external libraries

Tags: json, bash

I am trying to read a JSON file and execute a command on each object. The JSON is in the following format:

```json
    [
        {
            "table": "table_name",
            "items": [
                {
                    "Key": "k1",
                    "Value": "v1"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "k2",
                    "Value": "v2"
                }
            ]
        }, {...}
    ]
```

Currently I have a bash script that reads the JSON file and sends its content along with table name to a python script that then returns the appropriate items. So now I have a variable `items` that holds objects, e.g. `{ "Key": "k1", "Value": "v1" }, {"Key": "k2", "Value": "v2" }`. How do I split the string so that I can get each object separately.

The loop

```bash
    for item in $items; do
        echo "Item: $item"
    done
```

should print out

```
Item: { "Key": "k1", "Value": "v1" }
Item: { "Key": "k2", "Value": "v2" }
```

Overall the script will contain 2 loops - one that iterates over the tables and one that iterates over the json objects and uses them as parameters. How can I achieve this?

My current code looks like this:
bash:

```bash
tables=$(echo "$data" | grep -o '"table": *"[^"]*' | grep -o '"[^"]*$' | awk -F '"' '{print $2}')

for table in $tables; do
    items=$(echo "$data" | python parse_json.py "$table" "$data")
    
    echo "$table ${items[@]}"
    IFS=',' read -r -a json_objects <<< "${items%,}"
done
```

python:

```py
import sys, json

table_name = sys.argv[1]
data = json.loads(sys.argv[2])

# Extract items for the current table
items = [item for entry in data if entry['table'] == table_name for item in entry['items']]

# Output items as JSON strings
#print([f"{item}," if i != len(items) - 1 else item for i, item in enumerate(items)])
for i, item in enumerate(items):
    print(item) if i == len(items)-1 else print(f"{item},")
```

Comment: When you write _without external libraries_ does it mean not even using [`jq`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/)?

Comment: Yes, the point is that I do not have the option to install `jq` so I am looking for a solution without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, parsing JSON with the regular line editing tools in `bash` is very tricky! Assuming you get a number of items (with k=key/v=value pairs) in one line (e.g. `{ "Key": "k1", "Value": "v1" }, {"Key": "k2", "Value": "v2" }`); you could do something like this (using your example data in `$line_with_items`):

```
_get_item() {
   # from "X": "Y" get: "Y"
   ITEM="$1"
   IFSorg=$IFS
   IFS=:
   set -- $ITEM
   VALUE="$2"

   # from "Y" get: Y
   IFS='"'
   set -- $VALUE
   VALUE="$2"
   IFS=$IFSorg
   echo "$VALUE"
}

line_with_items='{ "Key": "k1", "Value": "v1" }, {"Key": "k2", "Value": "v2" }'
items=$(echo $line_with_items|sed 's/,/;/g;s/[{}]//g')

IFSorg=$IFS
IFS=';'
set -- $items
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
   KEY="$(_get_item \"$1\")"
   VAL="$(_get_item \"$2\")"
   shift; shift
   echo "Key=$KEY Value=$VAL"
done
IFS=$IFSorg
```

You will get:

```
Key=k1 Value=v1
Key=k2 Value=v2
```

But I would not setup your code like you've described. You're already using Python in there, you can easily parse JSON with Python and feed it to your bash script anyway you want so it will be much easier to parse the data. (Or do everything in Python!)

You can also use [jq](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/) which is a cool tool to parse JSON in bash! Then you wouldn't need the Python part anymore...

Comment: "Assuming you get a number of items (with k=key/v=value pairs) in one line " — That's one heck of an assumption to make given the example data in the question shows an array, containing an object, containing an array of objects split over multiple lines!

Comment: True, and I didn't test the code in the question but have to go with the assumption that this is what the bash script gets from the Python script with this data, as described. IMO without parsing all the JSON with Python or jq this will always be prone to error...